# Change loop from while to for

Tags: php, html

I have one `while` loop which gives output from 00:00 to 23:30.But I want same result with `for` loop.

Code:

```
<select>
<?php 
    $start_time = "00:00:00";
    $end_time = "23:00:00";
    while(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){?>
        <option value="<?php date("H:i:s", strtotime($start_time))?>"> <?php echo date("H:i A", strtotime($start_time))?></option>
        <?php $start_time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("$start_time + 15 minutes"));
    }

?></select>
```

Comment: wouldn't you need an array for `while` or `for` to work...?

Comment: Why do you want to change that if it works? `while` loop may be the better solution for that task.

Comment: Why You want to go to a for Loop? You will have no advantige from this.

Comment: My sir is asking for that to change in FOR loop :(

Comment: You need to be more clear. What is the purpose of this changing?

Comment: I'm also curious about why you would want to change to a FOR loop. A while loop is way more appropriate for what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy.

```
while(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time))
```

transforms to

```
for(;strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time);)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php 
   for($start_time="00:00:00",$end_time = "23:00:00";strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time); $start_time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("$start_time + 15 minutes")))
   {
?>
        <option value="<?php date("H:i:s", strtotime($start_time))?>"> <?php echo date("H:i A", strtotime($start_time))?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php 
    $start_time = "00:00:00";
    $end_time = "23:00:00";
    for($time = strtotime($start_time); $time <= strtotime($end_time);  $time += 900) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php date("H:i:s", $time)?>"> 
        <?php echo date("H:i A",$time)?>
        </option>
        <?php 
    }

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
<select>
<?php 
    $start_time = "00:00:00";
    $end_time = "23:00:00";
    for($i = strtotime($start_time); $i <= strtotime($end_time);  $i += 900) {
?>
        <option value="<?php date("H:i:s", $i)?>"><?php echo date("H:i A",$i)?></option>
<?php 
    }

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$start_time = "00:00:00";
$end_time = "23:00:00";
for($i=strtotime($start_time);$i <= strtotime($end_time);$i+=15*60){?>
    <option value="<?php date("H:i:s", $i)?>"> <?php echo date("H:i A", $i)?></option>
    <?php 
}

?>
```